# How to use SoapUI's xml in php

Tags: php, xml, soap

I have SoapUI working with this xml, but I need to consume that data on my server using php 5.3. I think I need to convert my $string into an array. the $xml = (array)simplexml_load_string($string); isn't throwing any errors, but the response from the call is NULL.

```
$string =   '
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tran="http://www.cornerstoneondemand.com/Webservices/TranscriptAndTask">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-115E54B97689076253912">
                <wsse:Username>me</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">word</wsse:Password>
                <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">dvhXLFiL4Aoi2KQ==</wsse:Nonce>
                <wsu:Created>2016-10-19T15:26:02.539Z</wsu:Created>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
      <tran:GetTranscriptAndTasks>
         <tran:request>
            <Request corpName="learning">
                <User id="me">
                    <RequestTypes>
                        <Inbox/>
                        <Transcript inprogressOnly="false" pageNumber="1"/>
                        <Session pageNumber="1" upcomingOnly="true"/>
                        <Assigned assignedOnly="true"/>
                        <Approval approvalDateRequested="1967-08-13"/>
                        <Task pendingTasksOnly="true"/>
                        <SuggestedTraining pageNumber="1"/>
                    </RequestTypes>
                </User>
            </Request>
         </tran:request>
      </tran:GetTranscriptAndTasks>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
';


$xml = (array)simplexml_load_string($string);

$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => 1));

$response = $soapClient->GetTranscriptAndTasks($xml);
var_dump($response);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**  I found https://github.com/sapankumarmohanty/lamp/blob/master/Crate-XML-2-Array that turns the xml into a nice array. But my result is still NULL...
I copied the WSDL here http://www.markforsyth.com/TranscriptAndTaskService.wsdl if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use xml code from SoapUI allmost direct.

Here are some code fragments from a code of mine:

**Constructor for my class, that servs as a interface to a web service. wsdl is defined as a constant in the class:**

```
public function __construct($username, $password) {
    $this->client = new SoapClient(self::wsdl);
    $this->client->__setSoapHeaders(self::securityHeader($username, $password));
}
```

**Function in my class that return a security header used in the constructor:**

```
private static function securityHeader($username, $password) {
    $nsWSSE = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd";
    $nsWSU = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd";
    $nonce = 'xxxxx';

    $xml = '<nsWSSE:Security xmlns:nsWSSE="' . $nsWSSE . '" xmlns:nsWSU="' . $nsWSU . '">'
        . '<nsWSSE:UsernameToken>'
        . '<nsWSSE:Username>' . $username . '</nsWSSE:Username>'
        . '<nsWSSE:Password>' . $password . '</nsWSSE:Password>'
        . '<nsWSSE:Nonce>' . $nonce . '</nsWSSE:Nonce>'
        . '<nsWSU:Created>' . gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z') . '</nsWSU:Created>'
        . '</nsWSSE:UsernameToken>'
        . '</nsWSSE:Security>';

    $securityToken = new SoapVar($xml, XSD_ANYXML);

    return new SoapHeader($nsWSSE, 'Security', $securityToken);
}
```

**A function in my class, that makes a request to the WS-function "abc":**

```
public function abc() {
    $xml = ... paste your xml code from SoapUI here ...
    $param = new SoapVar($xml, XSD_ANYXML);
    return $this->client->abc($param);
}
```

Comment: This has gotten me closer than ever! Now instead of NULL I get back <Result xmlns="" errCode="-1" errDescr="Request xml is empty".  if I enter the SoapUI xml in the GetTranscriptAndTasks() or nothing, I get the same error.

Comment: Now I'm just guessing:
Your copy-past of the xml code should start at `<tran:GetTranscriptAndTasks>`. But by starting at this point you mis the definition of the "tran" namespace, besause it is defined in the start of the xml code. Solution: add `xmlns:tran="http://www.cornerstoneondemand.com/Webservices/TranscriptAndTask"` to the `<tran:GetTranscriptAndTasks>` item

Comment: @kurt-larson hopefully you can turn your smarts loose on this one too [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40599636/php-calling-soap)